# Mysql and the date function, does it process it on each row?

Tags: mysql, date

I have a query that does a search by date. Here is the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(listing.trackdate,'%Y-%m-%d') >= STR_TO_DATE('$search_sdate','%m/%d/%Y')
```

Does MySQL have to process the date_format and str_to_date for each row to fulfill the where clause? Or is there a more optimized way of doing that? The field in the table is a datetime type. Its MySQL version 5.x. $search_sdate is a date received from a web form.

**Edit:**
To clarify I want to compare part of the date field. The date field type is a datetime that stores the date plus the time of when each row was inserted. But for this particular where clause I just want to compare the date portion of the field. Hopefully that clarifies it better, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: did u try ??`DATE(( STR_TO_DATE( "' . $$search_sdate. '", "%Y-%m-%d" ) )`  what u want to do?? compare between dates???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking the right question. To generalize it a bit, you should avoid SQL statements that include operations of any type on a table field of any type. Not only does it add processing for every record being considered, but it also prevents the optimizer from including any indexes including that field.

If you want an answer involving a range of times (say a date), use "WHERE datetimefield BETWEEN (midnight and midnight)" - or more precisely, "WHERE datetimefield >= midnight and datetimefield < nextmidnight".

Comment: when you say midnight do you mean something like '2011-01-01 00:00:00'?

Comment: I expect it would work fine to use "datefield >= "STR_TO_DATE('2011-01-01') AND datefield < STR_TO_DATE('2011-01-02')". The problem isn't using a date function, the problem is using a function on a table field. The optimizer is going to create two static date values that comprise the bounds of the search.

Answer (score 1):

If `listing.trackdate` *is* a `DATE` field, why does it need formatting to be compared with another date? It appears you're taking a date value and turning it into a string so that you can compare it with a string value that you've turned into a date.

The redundancy in that approach should, I hope, be apparent.

As to the first question you ask, of course `DATE_FORMAT(listing.trackdate)` must be evaluated for every row, as the value in that field will change. But it seems that

```
WHERE listing.trackdate >= STR_TO_DATE('$search_sdate','%m/%d/%Y')
```

should suffice, if `trackdate` is, indeed, a DATE field.

Comment: Aye. He probably doesn't even need to format the string. mySql should do it for him.. I know sql server would.

Comment: @Nicklamort I agree, but I'm not familiar enough with MySQL's behavior to comfortably include that in my answer. :)

Comment: @djacobson Its not a date field, its a datetime field. So it has the date and time in the field. I do the formatting to make sure its only comparing the dates and not the time portion of the datetime field.

Comment: @John You won't need to. If you didn't enter a time when "insert"ing these records, they will all be a default time and it won't matter anyway.

Comment: @Nicklamort when a row is inserted it does add a time. I needed the time for something else.

Comment: @John The fact that you only want to compare *part* of the data in the field changes the applicable answers to your question substantially; please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: And in any case you should be comparing a range of times - i.e. between midnight and midnight. Any query you run that uses an expression on a field will not use indexes involving that field.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you able to perform the WHERE clause without the formatting functions? MySQL shouldn't need to format it properly in order to process a comparison. Your formatting should only be done in SELECT